# Geometric description of map from degree $3$ curve to $\mathbb{P}^2$ of degree $2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $\overline{C} \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ be a smooth curve of degree $3$. Let $x, y \in \overline{C}$ be two points and $z = x + y$. Now, it's evident $L(C)$ determines a morphism $f: \overline{C} \to \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $2$. However, I don't have much geometric intuition here, and I am wondering what is a geometric description of the map $f$ in terms of lines in $\mathbb{P}^2$? How might I visualize this, perhaps with insight from the theory of Riemann surfaces?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  Your question is a bit unclear.  Are you defining the map from $\overline{C}$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$ by the complete linear system of the divisor $2\underline{z}$, where the invertible sheaf of the divisor $\underline{x}+\underline{y}+\underline{z}$ equals $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)|_{\overline{C}}$?

Comment: What is "evident"? If $\bar{C}$ is not hyperelliptic, there is no $g^1_2$ on $\bar{C}$, so the complete linear system $|x+y|$ has dimension $0$, and the corresponding rational map is constant.

Comment: What is $L(C)$?